# convert a string from ISO-8859-5 to UTF8

Tags: c#, encoding, utf-8, windows-mobile

I'm writing an application for windows mobile. I use a scan, i get a string encoding ISO-8859-5.How do I convert a string in UTF8?

Here is my code

```
var str_source = "³¿±2";
        Console.WriteLine(str_source);
        Encoding iso = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-5");
        Encoding utf8 = Encoding.UTF32;
        byte[] utfBytes = utf8.GetBytes(str_source);
        byte[] isoBytes = Encoding.Convert(utf8, iso, utfBytes);
        var str_result = iso.GetString(isoBytes, 0, isoBytes.Length);
        Console.WriteLine(str_result);
```

Comment: Why you say utf8 but you use utf32?

Answer (score 3):

You should never start off your testing code with using string literals when dealing with encoding issues. Always use bytes to start with.

```
        Encoding iso = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-5");
        Encoding utf = Encoding.UTF8;

        var isoBytes = new byte[] { 228, 232 }; // фш
        // iso to utf8
        var utfBytes = Encoding.Convert(iso, utf, isoBytes);
        // utf8 to iso
        var isoBytes2 = Encoding.Convert(utf, iso, utfBytes);

        // get all strings (with the correct encoding)
        // all 3 strings will contain фш
        string s1 = iso.GetString(isoBytes);
        string s2 = utf.GetString(utfBytes);
        string s3 = iso.GetString(isoBytes2);
```

Edit: If you do want to use string literals to get you started, then you can use the code below to change their encoding (Encoding.Unicode) to the expected 'incoming text' encoding:

```
        string stringLiteral = "фш";
        Encoding.Convert(Encoding.Unicode, Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-5"),
           Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(stringLiteral)); // { 228, 232 }
```

Comment: "you should never..." why?

Comment: @Adriano-Repetti It throws in another encoding in the equation and it's not the way your software will receive the string in the first place. But for the sake of preserving the knowledge, i added the required statement to convert a string literal to the required encoding.